# Como obter configurações da aplicação em classes estáticas no AspNet Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

No projeto Web da minha aplicação tenho o **appsettings.json**:

```
{
   "Foo": "Exemplo"
},
```

E tenho uma classe que reflete essa configuração:

```
public class FooSettings
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

No **startup.cs** eu leio e registro para usar via injeção de dependência:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    ...
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<FooSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Foo")); //lê e injeta dependênc
    ...
}
```

**Tudo Ok até aqui.** 
Posso obter uma instância de FooSettings via injeção de dependência em construtores e funciona sem problemas.

**A dúvida é:
E pra obter em uma classe estática?** No Asp.Net MVC 5 era assim:

```
public static class Exemplo
{
    private static readonly string Foo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Foo");
}
```

O ConfigurationManager pegava direto do web.config

Como fazer isso no Asp.Net Core 1.1?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um construtor estático?

Comment: @RodolphoSa eu nem sabia que isso existia. Mas infelizmente esses construtores não podem ter parâmetros.